# Groups with single conjugacy class of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I wish to know all those groups in which there is single conjugacy class of subgroups of fixed order.For example, In finite cyclic groups and in Alternating group of degree 4, number of conjugacy class of subgroups of fixed order is one.
But I am unable to search a general result.
Please Help me.

Comment: To be facetious, all groups have a unique conjugacy class of subgroups of order $1$. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I think the question is: Classify the (finite?) groups $G$ such that for every cardinal number $n$, $G$ has at most one conjugacy class of subgroups of order $n$. There are lots of examples, but I don't see too much of a pattern.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought the question probably was. An alternative possibility might be classify groups all finite groups for which there is a unique class of subgroups of all orders dividing the group order (there might be a better chance of answering that one, but it's still hard). But since $A_4$ does not satisfy those conditions, I guess that was not intended. I think people ought to ask comprehensible questions if they expect an answer.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for not asking the question in proper manner.@DerekHolt  And Thanks to @Jack Schmidt.

Comment: I should write it in following form. **Classify those finite groups in which subgroups of same order are conjugate.**