# Groups with single conjugacy class of subgroups. (modified)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am going to modify my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757559/groups-with-single-conjugacy-class-of-subgroups).

What are those finite non abelian groups in which non normal subgroups of same order are conjugate.

e.g. Dihedral groups of order $4n+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of examples. Many Frobenius groups have this property (that includes the dihedral groups of twice odd order, and other examples such as nonabelian groups of order $pq$ for primes $p,q$).

$A_4$, $A_5$, ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ and ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ are examples. It seems likely that $A_5$ is the only nonabelian simple group with this property, and it should not be too difficult to check that. In fact I would guess that $A_5$ is the only possible nonabelian composition factor of such a group. The Frobenius group $11^2:{\rm SL}(2,5)$ is another interesting example.

But I think it would be difficult to come up with a complete description, so you might need to ask a more directed question.

Comment: when you write "...and it shouldn't be too difficult to check that", do you mean to check for **all** the non-abelian simple groups (including infinite ones...), or precisely the alternating ones? Because for the alternating ones it is trivial (as $\;\langle (12)(345)\rangle\;,\;\;\langle (123456)\rangle\;$ are example of non-conjugate subgroups of order $\;6\;$ in $\;A_n\;,\;\;n>5\;$ , but for general simple groups it doesn't seem to be an easy task...or perhaps I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: I was talking only about finite simple groups, because the question specified that the group is finite. Perhaps "it should not be too difficult" should be replaced by "it should be possible". I am fairly sure there is a known list of finite simple groups with a unique conjugacy class of elements of order $2$, which would get you started. But I am not planning to check this myself any time soon!

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a simple point I was missing.